# Share USB drive between computers

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, usb

Does a program exist where I can share the USB memory stick contents connected to my computer with other computers wirelessly (bluetooth/wifi/etc...)?

I need it to be:

- free
- windows (xp), vista, 7 compatible
- easy to use (not too much setup required)
- shared with read/write permissions

Preferably:

- portable
- OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and above compatible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Bitvise](http://www.bitvise.com/index)

You could share any folder on your computer by installing [Bitvise SSH Server](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) and using it to set up one or more virtual accounts.

***Server Setup***

1. Install Bitvise SSH Server, and click on **Open Easy Settings** once the setup finishes
2. In the *1. Server settings* tab, enable **Automatically configure router (requires UPnP)**, and change the setting *Open Windows Firewall* to **Open port(s) to any computer**
3. Under the *3. Virtual accounts* tab, set up one or more accounts making sure to enable the **Allow file transfer** option, and the **Allow full access** for the *Virtual filesystem layout*

[image]

4. Save and exit. Then make sure to set up the appropriate permissions for your USB stick. You could do that through *Right click ==> Properties ==> Sharing ==> Advanced Sharing... ==> Permissions ==> Full control for Everyone*

[image]

***Client Access***

You could use any FTP client to access the files from any device on the network. Just use the username and password of the **virtual account** created in step 3. You could use the [Bitvise SSH client](http://www.bitvise.com/ssh-client-download), or opt for [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php) or [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1) for their portability

***Summary***

Set up Bitvise SSH Server on the main computer and use any FTP client to access it:

- It is free for personal use only
- Runs on Windows
- Easy to use (3-step setup)
- Shares folders with read/write permissions
- Clients can be portable such as WinSCP or FileZilla. The server must be installed
  OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard) and above compatible
- Clients, such as FileZilla, can be installed on OSX

Answer (score 3):

I may suggest you a FlexiHub solution - http://www.flexihub.com/usb-over-ip-software.html:

- use it for free with short sessions or buy and use without limitations
- compatible with all windows
- easy to use (you just need to create an account and share your USB to any place)
  But as I know it is not compatible with MacOS for now... But it works with virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It doesn't seem right for *me*, but I hope it helps someone else in the future! :)